# Swup JS stuck on "pageLoaded" state

Tags: swup, page-transition

Hello I am trying to make use of this awesome plugin "Swup JS".
When I run the code from their site the plugin runs perfectly.

When I try to add it in my website it stuck in the state "pageLoaded".

I have tried to remove all the code and paste each part separately but the error keeps happening.
Basically the URL is changing and the animation is working (until the fade-out part), but the new content never loads.
The debugger plugin shows that it goes until this part "pageLoaded" without any error.

Has anyone ever used this plugin or found this error?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and realised it was due to the "transition-fade" class animation not being applied to the HTML correctly. This is covered under the documentations [common issues](https://swup.js.org/common-issues) under: **Missing style for transition- class** section.

To resolve your problem make sure your swup element has an animation class linked to it, and that you have correctly referenced the animation in your stylesheet.

```css
.transition-fade {
  transition: 0.4s;
  opacity: 1;
}

html.is-animating .transition-fade {
  opacity: 0;
}
```